# Layout Manager for background images and text

Tags: java, swing, layout, gridbaglayout, imageicon

I'm trying to think of the best layout manager to achieve the picture below. I know absolute positioning is what I am used to, but I can't get the background image using this. `GridBagLayout` is excellent, but horrifically hard when ever I try I get a separate image for each grid.

Does anyone know an easy way out of this, or easy code to achieve the following?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of ways you can achieve this.

The simplest might be to just use what's already available[image]...

If you don't need the background to be scaled at run-time (ie you can get away with a non-resizable window), simply using a `JLabel` as the primary container could make your life significantly easier.

```
public class LabelBackground {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new LabelBackground();
    }

    public LabelBackground() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new LoginPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class LoginPane extends JLabel {

        public LoginPane() {
            try {
                setIcon(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/background.jpg"))));
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
            gbc.insets = new Insets(2, 2, 2, 2);
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;

            JLabel nameLabel = new JLabel("Name: ");
            nameLabel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
            JLabel passwordLabel = new JLabel("Password: ");
            passwordLabel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);

            add(nameLabel, gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
            add(passwordLabel, gbc);

            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
            gbc.gridx++;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            add(new JTextField(20), gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
            add(new JTextField(20), gbc);

            gbc.gridy++;
            gbc.insets = new Insets(10, 2, 2, 2);
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
            add(new JButton("Submit"), gbc);

        }

    }

}
```

**Updated with example of left alignment**

At the end of the constructor, add...

```
JPanel filler = new JPanel();
filler.setOpaque(false);
gbc.gridx++;
gbc.weightx = 1;
add(filler, gbc);
```

[image]

You might like to take a look at [How to use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) for more details

Comment: awesome! just one question, how did you lay it out so the txt fields were at the middle if i wanted it in the far left, what would i change?

Comment: If you want to move all the content over to the far left, I would add a transparent panel at `gridx` position 2 (to the right of the text fields) and give it a `weightx` of `1`

Comment: I added an additional example

Comment: +1, I agree there is no need to reinvent the wheel with custom painting panels when you just need to display the image at its actual size.

Comment: @camickr mis-using an "accidental" container (like JLabel) as-a container is a .. dirty hack - that has nothing to do with avoiding re-invention ;-) Instead, extend the general purpose container (like JPanel) and enhance with supporting background images. Or use a framework (like SwingX) which already has a container with such enhanced functionality via swingx painters (plus more, like supporting scrollable, transparency ..)

Comment: @kleopatra I would argue that in the absence of dedicate "image" component, this is an acceptable solution.  I agree, if you want something more robust and that has more features, you're going to have to write your own.  In this case I would argue that SwingX is a little heavy handed, but in the absence of overall requirements, this demonstrates the use of a layout manager as required by OP

Answer (score 4):

There are several ways to do it. These are what I can think of at the moment:

1. Create a subclass of [`JComponent`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html).
2. Override the [`paintComponent(Graphics g)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paintComponent%28java.awt.Graphics%29) method to paint the image that you want to display.
3. [Set the content pane](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setContentPane%28java.awt.Container%29) of the `JFrame` to be this subclass.

Some sample code:

```
class ImagePanel extends JComponent {
    private Image image;
    public ImagePanel(Image image) {
        this.image = image;
    }
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
    }
}

// elsewhere
BufferedImage myImage = ImageIO.read(...);
JFrame myJFrame = new JFrame("Image pane");
myJFrame.setContentPane(new ImagePanel(myImage));
```

Note that this code does not handle re-sizing the image to fit the `JFrame`, if that's what you wanted.

Comment: Before `frame.setVisible(true);`.

Comment: If that is where `frame.setVisible(true);` is, then yes.

Comment: `public static void main(String args[])

    { 

        JFrame f = new JFrame();

        f.setVisible(true);

        BufferedImage myImage = ImageIO.load();

        JFrame myJFrame = new JFrame("Image pane");

        myJFrame.setContentPane(new ImagePanel(myImage));


    }`

doesnt work because of.load

Comment: That is where you put the location of the image to put as the background to your JFrame.  You don't have anything for it to load, giving you an error.

Comment: It's `ImageIO.read(...)`, `ImageIO` takes, amongst other things, a `File` or `URL` @user1992697 It might useful to take the time to read the docs when faced with an issue like this.  You might find [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html) of some help. Beware, that `ImageIO` throws an `IOException` as well ;)

Comment: +1 For suggesting creating a subclass of JComponent (or even JPanel) and overriding paintComponent(). In fact, combining these two will provide a very elegant and reusable solution to the problem.