# Background Image of a window in Java using JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe

So, I've recently started learning Java, and I am really enjoying it despite the several issues and things that I have not yet understood, it makes me keep going on with it. So, considering that it is my first ever programming language, bear with me on any "noob" mistakes I make.

So, I created a fullscreen window using JFrame:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class Main extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Window
        JFrame mainWindow = new JFrame("Day One");
        mainWindow.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH); 
        mainWindow.setUndecorated(true);
        mainWindow.setVisible(true);
        //End Window

    }

}
```

And then I tried to add a background image to the window by adding this:

```
        mainWindow.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        mainWindow.setContentPane(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Recordings\\Desktop\\Day One\\Images\\Main-Background-Image.png")));
        mainWindow.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
```

I found this code [here](http://java-demos.blogspot.pt/2012/09/setting-background-image-in-jframe.html) but it isn't working at all. In this website there are two different ways of making it but I have tried both of them and none works.

I have also searched here, in stackoverflow, for similar questions, but all of them were either unanswered or answered with the same example as mine.

I really hope I have been clear enough, thank you very much for your time

EDIT:

As suggested, I have separated the long single statement:

```
            mainWindow.setContentPane(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Recordings\\Desktop\\Day One\\Images\\Main-Background-Image.png")));
```

Into three more easier debugged statements:

```
        ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Recordings\\Desktop\\Day One\\Images\\Main-Background-Image.png");
        JLabel label = new JLabel(image);
        mainWindow.setContentPane(label);
```

Comment: Don't try to write all you code in a single statement. You can't do any debugging when you do that. Instead create a JLabel as a separate statement and then you can invoke the setContentPane(...) using this label variable. The reason you do this is first you test your code by just invoke label.setText(...). Once that is working you try using label.setIcon(). If it doesn't work then you know the problem is the reading of your Icon. Then you can ask a clear and concise question stating what the problem is. Too basic debugging first!

Comment: Thank You for your answer! I am sorry if my question was not concise and clear enough, I will try to improve my future questions based on your suggestions which I appreciate! I have done what you told me to do, I separated the long statement into 3 different ones so It's easier to debug. Unfortunately it still isn't working. I have added them to the end of the topic. Once again thanks for your time :)

Comment: `Unfortunately it still isn't working` - still isn't working is NOT a description of the problem. You missed the first part of my comment on debugging the code is steps. 1) Did it work when you just displayed a label with text? Did you read the Icon successfully? Does the Icon have a valid size?

Comment: Don't use the "code snippet". Instead select your code and use the `{}` button.

Comment: @camickr Thanks for the quick answers & for editing the topic and put it in the right way. I have now understood what you meant, and have identified the problem as being relative to the label. I created a label with a string and it didn't appear. I don't know if it has anything to do with the fact that the frame is fullscreened.

Comment: are you trying to achieve a program like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14926425/layout-manager-for-background-images-and-text)? I didn't see an *explicit question* being asked in the original post, so I hesitated on replying with my adaptation between your post and the one I linked.

Comment: `I created a label with a string and it didn't appear.` - ok, so now post the code you actually execute, not as code snippets. We don't know the order of how the code snippets are executed. For example the components need to be added to the frame BEFORE the frame is made visible. We can't tell what you are doing based is code snippets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a few tips

- Its usually best to put a panfel within a frame and then add components to that. Makes for good containment when swing classes get a bit bigger.
- Its better to create a resource folder for your projects. Create one in the source of your project e.g. where the src and bin folders are located for your project and name it "resources".
- When creating and image icon its good practice to surround with a try catch so you can give appropriate errors and locate easily, or even handle the error at runtime.

With all that being said, here is your code with a little extra. It creates a panel to hold the jlabel(image) and it adds that panel to the frame. It creates an image icon with a quick method, all you have to do is pass in the file name. This method assumes you have created the folder in your project directory called resources and placed your image in there.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Window
    JFrame mainWindow = new JFrame("Day One");
    mainWindow.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH); 
    mainWindow.setUndecorated(true);

    //Create image
    JLabel imageHolder = new JLabel();
    imageHolder.setIcon(makeImageIcon("example.png"));

    //Add image to panel, add panel to frame
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.add(imageHolder);

    mainWindow.add(panel);

    mainWindow.setVisible(true);
}

//Creates imageicont from filename
public static ImageIcon makeImageIcon(String filename) {
    BufferedImage myPicture = null;
    try {
        myPicture = ImageIO.read(new File("resources/" + filename));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return new ImageIcon(myPicture);
}
```

Hope this helps